# Survey123 auto-export to Excel

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I am looking for a way to auto-export a Survey123 submission into an Excel file, each time a form is submitted. Does anyone have any experience or workflows on how to make this happen or if it is possible? The aim is to be able have auto-exported Excel sheets saving to company drive so those who do not have access to ArcGIS Online can easily access data. I have seen options for integration with Microsoft Power Automate for appending results into an existing sheet but this will not work - I need each submission in their own Excel sheet. I also do not have access to Esri Enterprise / workflow manager.

Comment: I do this with one of our surveys (in order to notify relevant people of submissions that need their attention).  However, it's not automated based on when a submission occurs, but rather it polls the survey's feature layer every 3 hours during the working day.  It uses the REST end point for the feature layer to query for new features (survey submissions) and ustilises a token for authentication

Comment: ... I don't actually export to Excel, but rather just generate a new email for each submission.  Exporting to Excel would be fairly simple though, once you've extracted the data from the feature service.